# Set up phone sign-up and sign-in with custom policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am working on Azure AD B2C phone sign-up and sign-in with custom policies. I followed the documentation and completed the flow and it's working fine as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/phone-authentication).
But I want to remove that additional email address verification from the phone number signup flow. I am trying by editing the custom policies but I couldn't make it. Please help me.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/media/phone-authentication/email-verification.png

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JasSuri I tried it by editing <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="false" /> in LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber_CollectEmailAddress TechnicalProfile. And got this error AADB2C90037: An error occurred while processing the request. Please contact administrator of the site you are trying to access.

Comment: What you need to do is remove the orchestration step that calls LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonPhoneNumber_CollectEmailAddress entirely. Other user journeys or subsequent orchestration steps may rely on this email being populated so they may fail, and you’d need to resolve the logic/dependencies.

Comment: To effectively troubleshoot and provide logs, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

Comment: Hi @JasSuri Thank you and I will troubleshoot and check the logs.